# SwipeListview with QuickScroll or sectiondIndexer

Tags: android, listview, swipe-gesture, swipeview, sectionindexer

I am using SwipeListView [fortysevendeg](https://github.com/47deg/android-swipelistview) which is working fine and using this library i am able to swipe list items left/right. But now I am trying add section indexer in this listview to add alphabetical search indexer at the right side of list. For which i have found [this library](https://github.com/andraskindler/quickscroll). Both of these libraries works fine when used independently. But when i try to use both of them in single list view then swipelistview does'nt work properly. It effects the swipe animation and swipe gesture. Any suggestions.

Here is the code I am using:

XML:

```
<lib.swipelistview.SwipeListView
    xmlns:swipe="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/lv_UserConnections"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/progress_bottom"
    android:layout_below="@+id/layout_Connection"
    android:divider="@null"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp"
    android:listSelector="#00000000"
    swipe:swipeBackView="@+id/back_ProfileList"
    swipe:swipeCloseAllItemsWhenMoveList="true"
    swipe:swipeDrawableChecked="@drawable/choice_selected"
    swipe:swipeDrawableUnchecked="@drawable/choice_unselected"
    swipe:swipeFrontView="@+id/front_ProfileList"
    swipe:swipeMode="right" />

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progress_bottom"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="3dip"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" 
    android:visibility="visible" />

<com.andraskindler.quickscroll.QuickScroll
    android:id="@+id/quickscroll"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />
```

Code:

```
    userConnectionsListAdapter = new UserConnectionsListAdapter(mContext, userConnectionsList); 
    userConnectionsLV.addFooterView(footerView);    
    userConnectionsLV.setSwipeListViewListener(new BaseSwipeListViewListener());
    userConnectionsLV.setSwipeMode(SwipeListView.SWIPE_MODE_LEFT); // there are five swiping modes 
    userConnectionsLV.setOffsetRight(Utils.convertDpToPixel(0f, mContext)); // 
    userConnectionsLV.setOffsetLeft(Utils.convertDpToPixel(200f, mContext)); //
    userConnectionsLV.setAnimationTime(200); // Animation time
    userConnectionsLV.setSwipeCloseAllItemsWhenMoveList(true);

    userConnectionsLV.setAdapter(userConnectionsListAdapter);


    final QuickScroll fastTrack = (QuickScroll) view.findViewById(R.id.quickscroll);
    fastTrack.init(QuickScroll.TYPE_POPUP, userConnectionsLV, userConnectionsListAdapter, QuickScroll.STYLE_NONE);
    fastTrack.setFixedSize(2);
    fastTrack.setPopupColor(QuickScroll.BLUE_LIGHT, QuickScroll.BLUE_LIGHT_SEMITRANSPARENT, 1, Color.WHITE, 1);
```

Comment: IS that your whole xml file?

Comment: no this is not whole xml file, there is also a parent/root layout. All these elements are inside root